# Inconsistent Numpy array aliasing behavior

Tags: python, numpy

The following behavior is expected and is what I get. This is consistent with how aliasing works for native Python objects like lists.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> y = x
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> y
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> x = x + np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> x
array([3, 5, 7])
>>> y
array([1, 2, 3])
```

But the following behavior is unexpected by changing `x = x + np.array([2, 3, 4])` to `x += np.array([2, 3, 4])`

```
>>> x += np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> x
array([3, 5, 7])
>>> y
array([3, 5, 7])
```

The Numpy version is 1.16.4 on my machine. Is this a bug or feature? If it is a feature how `x = x + np.array([2, 3, 4])` differs from `x += np.array([2, 3, 4])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `y = x` doesn't create a copy of the array; it simply tells `y` to point to the same data as `x`, which you can see if you look at their `id`s:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = x
print(id(x), id(y))

(140644627505280, 140644627505280)
```

`x = x + np.array([2, 3, 4])` will do a reassignment of x to a new `id`, while `x += np.array([2, 3, 4])` will modify it in place. Thus, the `+=` will also modify y, while `x = x + ...` won't.

```
x += np.array([2, 3, 4])
print(id(x))
print(x, y)

x = x + np.array([2, 3, 4])
print(id(x))
print(x, y)

140644627505280
[3 5 7] [3 5 7]
140644627175744
[ 5  8 11] [3 5 7]
```

Comment: The main takeaway from this: whenever you are confused about "aliasing" (as the OP refers to it), make generous use of `print(id(x))` to see what is going on, and that typically clears things up.